# Elements $A\in GL_4(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ with $A^5=I, A\neq I$ by using GAP.

Tags: matrices, group-theory, gap, magma

I need elements  $A\in GL_4(\mathbb{Z}_2)$(General linear group of $4\times 4$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ) with $A^5=I, A\neq I.$ By using simple calculation its hard to find such types of elements. So i think GAP or Magma is suitable for it. I am new in GAP. Please suggest me how to find this types of matrices with a suitable LoadPackage(if necessary). Thanks.

Comment: This is the same question as asking for subgroups of order $5$, which is a standard GAP call.

Comment: Yes it is same but i am new in GAP please if possible tell me a command ....thanks..

Comment: gap>g:=GL(4,2); then what command should i use ?

Comment: One can easily write down such matrices by hand: the companion matrix of $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ and its conjugates.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown OK i am writing and will inform....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes you right ....but i want to know GAP command so that  i will work for any finite field .

Comment: There are 1344 such matrices. I suggest to look at the GAP Software Carpentry lesson - [the 1st episode](http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/01-command-line/) introduces all commands needed for doing that by a straightforward approach, and in some next episode you will see how one can use `ConjugacyClasses` to deal with properties that are invariants of conjugacy classes more efficiently.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov sir are you saying that if I took one matrix of order 5 then all of elements in its conjugate class are also of same order ... so I will get all 5 order elements ??

Comment: Yes, since in this case there is only one conjugacy class of elements of order 5.